# How important is it to keep UPS connections either filtered or not?

Tags: networking, power, ups

This question is somewhat difficult to summarize into a good title, so let me explain what I am talking about.

I have a setup where an ADSL modem connects to the telephone network. The power supply for the modem is through a UPS, but for various reasons the ADSL modem's WAN port is unfiltered (connected directly to the phone jack using only the ISP-supplied splitter). The ADSL modem's LAN/Ethernet port is connected to the input (unfiltered) Ethernet port on the UPS, and the output (filtered) Ethernet port on the UPS connects to my router which then forwards the connection over a wireless LAN. Both the modem and the router are on separate battery-backed outlets on the UPS, so barring extreme overvoltages there exists no possible connection path between the modem and the router that does not pass through the UPS. *Here's a diagram showing the setup:*

[image]

In this diagram (which is actually a part of a larger diagram and fixed up slightly for posting here), the large blueish box is the UPS with its various inputs and outputs. The thick red line is the unfiltered power input to the UPS, and the thin red line to the bottom right is the modem's WAN port connection to the phone network. The thin red line between "POTS/Eth in" and "ADSL modem" is the connection between the modem's LAN port and the unfiltered Ethernet port on the UPS. The small rectangular box on top is the router, which is only connected physically to ports on the UPS. The crossing lines are *not* connected.

Since I'll be moving from ADSL to fiber in the immediate future which will remove the only non-UPS-filtered conductive input line (replacing the telephone line input with a fiberoptic cable), I don't want to spend too much time, money and effort on what might be a small risk.

While obviously exposing the ADSL modem's WAN input to the unfiltered telephone network presents a risk to the modem itself in case of an overvoltage or other similar condition on the telephone network, **what is the risk to the other equipment in a setup like this?** Specifically, do I need to worry about an electrical problem spreading from the modem to e.g. the router (coming in through the telephone network, jumping across to the electrical wiring and then across to another outlet on the UPS, while remaining inside the "UPS perimeter"), or is that a "you've got bigger things to worry about then, like the house fire" kind of situation?

My feeling is that with this setup if something happens that can reasonably cause damage to more than the modem's WAN circuitry I have bigger things to worry about than a fried router, but it would be nice if someone could confirm (or deny) it along with explaining the reasoning why that is so.